# Is it possible to hide suicide pills in beverages as beans, fruits, etc to assassinate someone

Tags: internal-consistency, assassination

Adam asks an alleged assassin to drink some of the beverage he had just bought.

Assassin did as bid. Adam was shocked.

Adam walked away and drank from the cup. He felt something in his mouth, then remembered it was the beans, the assassin had said.

Shrugging, he swallowed them or bit them all and ingested the cyanide and died.

Could the pill have dissolved or something, if so wouldn't it dissolve in saliva ?

Is the pill to large to be a bean? Can it be something else?

Is the scenario possible?

Comment: So the man is assassinated by drinking a suicide pill? Why is the assassin shocked? The pill can be any size, as far as I know, and it could be dissolved, but would that not kill the assassin unless he has some form of antidote? Or does the assassin simply not eat the "beans", in which case it's totally possible?

Comment: Changed genetic " man" to Adam from further confusion.

Comment: I assumed cyanide capsules are crunchy and incapable of being dissolved by liquids or at least saliva. Or maybe longer lasting or not . Probably couldn't save him from swallowing by accident though.

Comment: Is there any more info on this pill? Is it hard or soft, or chewy?

Comment: Greetings New Person!  Do take a moment to review the [help] and take the [tour] so you can learn about how this forum works, how to write good queries, etc. As it stands, your query needs some work. First of all, please ask only *one* question at a time. Also, please edit your query to eliminate anything unnecessary to understand the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: I think you meant to write "generic" instead of "genetic". The "t' and the "r" are located alongside each other on QWERTY keyboards.

Comment: Maybe the assassin should try using Iocane powder: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9s0UURBihH8

Answer (score 6):

**The Iceman Method**

There was a mafia hitman known as "The Iceman" for his method of freezing corpses in a meat locker for a few years before thawing them out so that when the cops found them the time of death would be way off and evidence would be scarce. He was said to have possibly killed over 300 people in his lifetime, and he had a method of doing it that he had perfected. He had a small aerosol bottle (kinda like those mint breath spray things that wanna be lady killers all carried around in the early 90's). He had filled it with liquid cyanide and propellant gas. He would walk up to his mark and ask them for the time, when they glanced down at Thier watch he would spritz them in the face and walk away. The cyanide killed so quickly that often times he killed this way in broad daylight in crowded areas and nobody standing around had any idea he had done it. His secret was in his nonchalance. He would calm and polite as can be walk up, ask the innocent question, and walk away as if nothing had happened and he was so good at it that nobody ever spotted him do it, not even once. He was only caught because he tried to buy cyanide from an undercover cop. People who directly witnessed him kill people in this manner usually thought the man he had spoken to had suffered a heart attack or a seizure.

Point being, there are a lot of ways to very suavely and discretely kill somebody with poison while being watched without ever attracting any attention or suspicion. It is apparently effective enough that The Iceman made an entire decades long career specializing in it. Your idea is perfectly valid and stranger things have already happened in real life.

Answer (score 5):

The number one requirement for something like that to work is the target needs to consume the bean.  Personally, if I felt something bean like in a drink of mine, I would spit it out.  My drinks don't have bean-like things in them.

An exception might be boba.  Popping boba is something you're expected to consume and pop.  Cyanide hidden in a popping boba would work.

As for what you put the cyanide capsule in, that depends 100% on what you want to put it in. You can put it in anything you want.  [From history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_pill):

> During World War II, British and American secret services developed the "L-pill" (lethal pill) which was given to agents going behind enemy lines. It was an oval capsule, approximately the size of a pea, consisting of a thin-walled glass ampoule covered in brown rubber to protect against accidental breakage and filled with a concentrated solution of potassium cyanide. It could be carried in the mouth, shaped as a false tooth; if it was accidentally swallowed it would pass harmlessly through the body. To use, the agent would bite down on the pill, crushing the ampoule to release the fast-acting poison. Brain death occurs within minutes and the heartbeat quickly stops.

Note that every aspect of that container had a rationale behind it  There was nothing forced.  They chose to make the capsule exactly that way.  It also shows just how small the capsule can be.

Comment: An expresso/coffee Martini might also work. Usually they put a few coffee beans in it as decoration and the drinker might eat those as well.

Answer (score 3):

If your main question is "Is the story possible" then the answer is definitely yes. You don't need much Cyanide to kill a person which means you can have a very small pill. Size isn't really the problem at all. Everything else you add onto it would be for texture/appearance/protection

Your assassin could also have an antidote of some kind store in a fake tooth or already consumed before hand that could protect him from the poison. This would allow you to basically use Bwrites Ice method and not poison yourself, or inject it into fruit and not have to worry too much. (I don't know how an antidote works, I assume its just a poison generally has an antidote which counteracts its effects)

For example, its pretty popular now to have passion fruit added into fruity drinks.You could disguise the pill as a seed which needs to be bitten which Adam does because he likes to bite them, while the assassin swallows it and it harmlessly passes through his system.

Answer (score 1):

### It is possible

It has been done a lot in the murder mystery genre *(I've read about 200+ detective mystery short stories/novels FWIW)*.

What you could do is you could put the poison inside an **Ice cube** so it is less suspicious and it will naturally dissolve in the drink.

Tell me what you think and I'll modify my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

If it just needs to be **swallowed**, it's a normal pill and you can make it look like practically whatever you want. The dissolving film doesn't need to be one particular shape or color in order to dissolve. Heat can also be an issue here, as most normal pills would dissolve in coffee temperatures for instance.

If the pill needs to be **crushed**, it just needs to be of a material that doesn't dissolve by swallowing. You might adjust the force to break the pill according to what it's imitating. It should also be natural to chew on while consuming the drink, which might limit it somewhat.

**Alternative** approaches include taste and odorless poison with an antidote that you take before or after drinking, which allow the assassin to drink while the victim dies. Or something that would dissolve over time, like an ice cube, so that the assassin can drink at the beginning, but it's poisonous when the victim consumes it later.